Derangements for couples in a round table

Question:
Let ( m(n) ) denote the number of ways of seating ( n ) married couples around a circle such that no husband sits next to his wife. Then, the remainder obtained on dividing ( m(5) ) by ( 5 ) is equal to?
My Attempt:
Total cases:
$ \text{Total cases} = 9! $
Defining an event $( P(i) ) $such that the ${( i )^{th}}$ couple sits together:
$ P(i) = 8! \cdot 2 \quad (\text{5 such terms}) $
$P(i) \cap P(j) = 7! \cdot 2^2 \quad (\text{10 such terms}) $
$ P(i) \cap P(j) \cap P(k) = 6! \cdot 2^3 \quad (\text{10 such terms}) $
Similarly:
$P(i) \cap P(j) \cap P(k) \cap P(l) = 5! \cdot 2^4 \quad (\text{5 such terms}) $
$P(i) \cap P(j) \cap P(k) \cap P(l) \cap P(m) = 4! \cdot 2^5 \quad (\text{1 such term}) $
Using the inclusion-exclusion principle:
$m(5) = 9! - \binom{5}{1} \cdot 8! \cdot 2 + \binom{5}{2} \cdot 7! \cdot 2^2 - \binom{5}{3} \cdot 6! \cdot 2^3 + \binom{5}{4} \cdot 5! \cdot 2^4 - \binom{5}{5} \cdot 4! \cdot 2^5 $
Now, compute ( m(5) ) modulo ( 5 ) to find the remainder:
$ m(5) \mod 5 = (362880 - 40320 + 20160 - 7680 + 1920 - 320) \mod 5 = 0 $
So, the remainder obtained on dividing $( m(5) )$ by $( 5 ) $is $( 0 )$.

This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Unable to understand your "un-mathjax" working, let me try and see.
Of the $5$ couples, if $k$ couples are together, the rest are left unconstrained
The couples together can be taken as glued together (so counted as one each), and flippable, while the rest can be permuted among the remaining seats (I take the seats to be unnumbered, so remember that the formula for seating $n$ people on a round table with $n$ unnumbered seats is $(n-1)!$),
Then # of ways for $k$ couples to be together, $\;\;S_k=\binom{5}{k}2^k(10−1−k)!$
And applying inclusion-exclusion,
$m(5) = 9! - \binom51 2^1 (8)! + \binom52 2^2 7! - \binom53 2^3 6! + \binom54 2^4 5! - \binom55 2^5 4!$
$= 112512$
Dividing $m(5)\;$ by $5$, I, too, get a remainder of $2$
